# docxtpl - error when opening document in Word after adding more than five images

Tags: python, python-docx

I'm trying to automate some reports in Word, and I'm getting the following error when I open the created document in Word:

"Word found unreadable content in test. Do you want to recover the contents of this document? If you trust the source of this document, click Yes."

After clicking yes it says the file cannot be opened. When I open in Libre Office there's no issue (I'm running the script on Ubuntu/Python 3.8.5)

Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
from docxtpl import DocxTemplate, InlineImage
from docx.shared import Mm

doc = DocxTemplate("template_test.docx")

""" load up images """
mps_chart = InlineImage(doc, image_descriptor='test/mps_line_chart.png')
server_pie = InlineImage(doc, image_descriptor='test/server_availability_pie.png', width=Mm(76), height=Mm(58))
agent_pie = InlineImage(doc, image_descriptor='test/agent_availability_pie.png', width=Mm(76), height=Mm(58))
cases_chart = InlineImage(doc, image_descriptor='test/cases_bar_chart.png')
alarms_chart = InlineImage(doc, image_descriptor='test/alarms_line_chart.png')
intro_alarms_graphic = InlineImage(doc, image_descriptor='test/alarms_intro_graphic.png', width=Mm(38), height=Mm(38))
intro_cases_graphic = InlineImage(doc, image_descriptor='test/open cases_intro_graphic.png', width=Mm(38), height=Mm(38))
intro_mps_graphic = InlineImage(doc, image_descriptor='test/mps_intro_graphic.png', width=Mm(38), height=Mm(38))
intro_doc_graphic = InlineImage(doc, image_descriptor='test/doc_intro_graphic.png', width=Mm(38), height=Mm(38))

months = {"MONTH_1": "June", "MONTH_2": "May", "MONTH_3": "April"}
intro_images = {"intro_alarms": intro_alarms_graphic, "intro_cases": intro_cases_graphic, "intro_mps": intro_mps_graphic, "intro_doc": intro_doc_graphic}
images = {"mps_line_chart": mps_chart, "agent_pie_chart": agent_pie, "server_pie_chart": server_pie , "alarms_line_chart": alarms_chart, "cases_bar_chart": cases_chart}

context = {**images, **months, **intro_images}

doc.render(context)
doc.save("test.docx")
```

The following will work fine, I only get the error when more than 5 images are added:

```
intro_images = {"intro_alarms": intro_alarms_graphic}
images = {"mps_line_chart": mps_chart, "agent_pie_chart": agent_pie, "server_pie_chart": server_pie , "alarms_line_chart": alarms_chart}
```

I also still have the same issue when I include all the images in a single dict, or if I do this:

```
context = {"mps_line_chart": mps_chart, "agent_pie_chart": agent_pie, "server_pie_chart": server_pie , "alarms_line_chart": alarms_chart, "cases_bar_chart": cases_chart, "intro_alarms": intro_alarms_graphic, "intro_cases": intro_cases_graphic, "intro_mps": intro_mps_graphic, "intro_doc": intro_doc_graphic}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seemed to be an issue with the Word document once it had been opened and saved again in Libre Office. I opened the template back in Word and saved which seems to have resolved the issue.